# Universal property definition from Greub's Multilinear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Hi I started studying Greub's multilinear algebra book and I found something very strange when he defines the tensor product of two vector spaces: He defines:

[...] Let $E$ and $F$ be vector spaces and let $\otimes$ be a bilinear
mapping from $E\times F$ into a vector space $T$. We shall say
that $\otimes$ has the universal property, if satisfies the following
conditions:

$\otimes_1$: The vectors $x\otimes y$ ($x\in E$, $y\in F$) generate $T$, **or
equivalently** $\textrm{img}(\otimes)=T$.

[...]

The problem is the equivalence: $$T=\textrm{span}\{x\otimes y: x\in E, y\in F\}\Leftrightarrow \textrm{img}(\otimes)=T. $$  Since $$\textrm{span}\{x\otimes y: x\in E, y\in F\}=\textrm{span}\{\textrm{im}(\otimes)\}$$ he is saying $T=\textrm{span}\{\textrm{im}(\otimes)\}$ if and only if $T=\textrm{img}(\otimes)$, in other words, he means $$\textrm{im}(\otimes)=\textrm{span}\{\textrm{im}(\otimes)\},$$ that sounds strange for me. Can anyone clarifies this?

Comment: I suppose $\operatorname{img}(\otimes)$ denotes the smallest vector space containing the set-theoretic image. Otherwise, you'd have a problem since not every element of $E \otimes F$ has the form $x \otimes y$ when both dimensions are $> 1$.

Answer (score 4):

At last line of the first page, the author says

> We shall denote by $\mathrm{Im\,}\varphi$ the subspace of $G$ *generated* by $S$.

where $S$ is the set of the images.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the author is defining the tensor product as $(T,\otimes)$ with certain properties, and will ultimately say "$T$ is unique up to isomorphism, and we call it $E\otimes F$."

You're right that the set theoretic image of the function $\otimes$ is not usually a vector space, it is just a subset of $E\otimes F$. The image is usually not even closed under addition. It does *span* $E\otimes F$, though.

I guess it hinges on the author's notation. I would have preferred to write $\langle im(\otimes)\rangle=T$ if I wanted to express the span. The author may have adopted some convention allowing them to omit the spanning angle brackets.